# CDK override bind when using LambdaIntegration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

When using `LambdaIntegration` class the bind function add permission to the lambda automatically:

```js
    bind(method) {
        super.bind(method);
        const principal = new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com');
        const desc = `${method.restApi.node.uniqueId}.${method.httpMethod}.${method.resource.path.replace(/\//g, '.')}`;
        this.handler.addPermission(`ApiPermission.${desc}`, {
            principal,
            scope: method,
            sourceArn: method.methodArn,
        });
        // add permission to invoke from the console
        if (this.enableTest) {
            this.handler.addPermission(`ApiPermission.Test.${desc}`, {
                principal,
                scope: method,
                sourceArn: method.testMethodArn,
            });
        }
    }
```

Currently, I create multiple API Gateways who 90% of them trigger the same lambda function, this causes me the following error :

```
The final policy size (XXX) is bigger than the limit (20480)
```

More info [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/337).

My goal is to override the bind function with my own function and handle the permissions by myself, something like that:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:{AWS_REGION}:{AWS_ACCOUNT}:{API_ID}/*/*/*
```

I know this is not a best practice but right now this is the only working workaround.

This is the new class I created :

```js
    class customLambdaIntegration extends apigateway.LambdaIntegration{
          myHandler: lambda.IFunction;
          constructor(handler: lambda.IFunction, options?: LambdaIntegrationOptions) {
            super(handler, options);
            this.myHandler = handler;
          }
          bind(method: Method) {
            const principal = new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com');
            const desc = `${method.restApi.node.uniqueId}.${method.httpMethod}.${method.resource.path.replace(/\//g, '.')}`;
            this.myHandler.addPermission(`ApiPermission.${desc}`, {
              principal,
              scope: method,
              sourceArn: method.methodArn.toString().replace(api.deploymentStage.stageName,'*')
            });
          }
        }
```

Getting this error when running `cdk list`:

```
if (!this.scope) { throw new Error('AwsIntegration must be used in API'); }
```

Problematic piece of code which throw the error:

```js
    class AwsIntegration extends integration_1.Integration {
        constructor(props) {
            const backend = props.subdomain ? `${props.subdomain}.${props.service}` : props.service;
            const type = props.proxy ? integration_1.IntegrationType.AWS_PROXY : integration_1.IntegrationType.AWS;
            const { apiType, apiValue } = util_1.parseAwsApiCall(props.path, props.action, props.actionParameters);
            super({
                type,
                integrationHttpMethod: props.integrationHttpMethod || 'POST',
                uri: cdk.Lazy.stringValue({ produce: () => {
                        if (!this.scope) {
                            throw new Error('AwsIntegration must be used in API');
                        }
                        return cdk.Stack.of(this.scope).formatArn({
                            service: 'apigateway',
                            account: backend,
                            resource: apiType,
                            sep: '/',
                            resourceName: apiValue,
                        });
                    } }),
                options: props.options,
            });
        }
        bind(method) {
            this.scope = method;
        }
    }
```

[LambdaIntegration documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaIntegration.html)

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

---

To whom this might be helpful, I open a feature request to implement my function and manually handle the lambda permission :

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5774

Comment: Can you open an issue for the policy size error referencing this question? https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/new?labels=bug%2C+status%2Fneeds-triage&template=bug.md

Comment: @jogold Sure, but this is cloudformation limitation and not CDK, do you still think i need to open a bug ?

Comment: I know about the CF limitation. You are right, not a bug but maybe a feature request to allow users to bypass automatic permission creation (sort of "manual mode") to avoid this limitation

Comment: @jogold Open a feature request

Comment: @AmitBaranes I added some more detail to the CDK issue you created, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Also where did you find that first snippet/code block ? I looked for a while but could not find the actual implementation of the bind() method anywhere ?

Comment: @DR. glad I could help, found this code under API gateway package  - node_modules\@aws-cdk\aws-apigateway\lib\integrations\lambda.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, `this['scope'] = method;` were missing inside the bind function since `AwsIntegration` class implements `this.scope=method`.

Full code :

```js
       class customLambdaIntegration extends apigateway.LambdaIntegration{
          // myScope : cdk.IConstruct;
          myHandler: lambda.IFunction;
          MyOptinos: apigateway.LambdaIntegrationOptions | undefined;
          constructor(handler: lambda.IFunction, options?: LambdaIntegrationOptions) {
            super(handler, options);
            this.myHandler = handler;
            this.MyOptinos = options;
          }
          bind(method: Method) {
            this['scope'] = method;
            const principal = new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com');
            const desc = `${method.restApi.node.uniqueId}.${method.httpMethod}.${method.resource.path.replace(/\//g, '.')}`;
            this.myHandler.addPermission(`ApiPermission.${desc}`, {
              principal,
              scope: method,
              sourceArn: method.methodArn.toString().replace(api.deploymentStage.stageName,'*')
            });
        }
      }
```