# How to give particular/full access to Elastic beanstalk using aws CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

I have created aws pipeline to deploy my dot net framework app to elastic beanstalk using CDK typescript code.

But in deploy step it fails with below error

> Insufficient permissions
>   The provided role does not have the elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion permission

I am not sure how to assign permissions using aws cdk.

How should I add permissions in below code

Below is my deploy stage code

```js
const appName = "SampleDotNetMVCWebApp";
const newRole = new iam.Role(this, "Role", {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com")
});

newRole.addToPolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    resources: ["*"],
    actions: ["elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion"]
  })
);

const app = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplication(this, "EBApplication", {
  applicationName: appName
});

const elbEnv = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, "Environment", {
  environmentName: "SampleMVCEBEnvironment",
  applicationName: appName,
  platformArn: platform,
  solutionStackName: "64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 v2.5.0 running IIS 8.5"
});

pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: "Deploy",
  actions: [   
    new ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction({
      actionName: "DeployToEB",
      applicationName: appName,
      environmentName: "SampleMVCEBEnvironment",
      input: cdkBuildOutput,
      role: newRole
    })
  ]
});
```

NOTE: In above code aws pipeline action "ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction" is custom action as aws cdk has not release this deploy to eb action feature yet.
You can check the issue and code for implementation of IAction here 
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively as suggested here - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2516

This issue can be resolved by adding policy in bind method of **ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction**

```js
public bind(scope: Construct, stage: codepipeline.IStage, options: codepipeline.ActionBindOptions):
      codepipeline.ActionConfig {
    options.role.addManagedPolicy(
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          "AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess"
        ));
  }
```

Comment: I like this workaround, although this is complex the solution a little bit.

Comment: True. But it keeps main code look natural. 
And the iam policy is taken care by the action class it self.

Comment: I have used the bind function as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713522/cdk-override-bind-when-using-lambdaintegration/59716246#59716246

Answer (score 1):

You need to add permissions to `ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction` to create `CreateApplicationVersion`, Use [`.addToPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Role.html#add-to-policystatement)

> These policies will be created with the role, whereas those added by
>   `addToPolicy` are added using a separate CloudFormation resource
>   (allowing a way around circular dependencies that could otherwise be
>   introduced).

```js
   const elasticBeanStalkDeployAction =  new ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction({
      actionName: 'DeployToEB',
      applicationName: appName,
      environmentName: 'SampleMVCEBEnvironment',
      input: cdkBuildOutput 
    })


    elasticBeanStalkDeployAction.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: ['*'],
      actions: ['elasticbeanstalk:*']
    }));
```

Later, use the object you created and pass it into the action:

```js
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
actions: [elasticBeanStalkDeployAction]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amit
I could not find .addToRolePolicy method on elasticBeanStalkDeployAction object so I created new role and added new policy statement using .addToPolicy method which is giving me error my aws user account is not authorised to assume role

Comment: I have edited question details to get the better understanding of this question.

Comment: To be honest, this is working for me, can you please share the specific error you getting?

Comment: Maybe I am making some silly mistake somewhere else in code. I am new to this cdk thing.
Anyway I have resolved this issue by adding managed policy in bind method of ElasticBeanStalkDeployAction class which implements IAction. As suggested here -
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2516

Will mark it as answer and will add my solution as well
Thanks a lot for all your help..!