# How to pass a stage variable to lambda function in api gateway using AWS CDK?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an API Gateway that triggers a lambda function specified by a stage variable `stageVariables.lbfunc`.

[image]

How can I create this kind of integration request with AWS CDK?

It looks like that I should create a special `handler` for [LambdaRestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaRestApi.html).

But I can't find any example code for doing this.

The following is my current code. I wish that `LambdaIntegration`'s handler can be determined by a stage variable.

```
# dev_lambda_function should be replaced by something else
dev_lambda_function = lambda_.Function(self, "MyServiceHandler",
            runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            code=lambda_.Code.asset("resources"),
            handler="lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            description="My dev lambda function"
            )
stage_options = apigateway.StageOptions(stage_name="dev", 
    description="dev environment", 
    variables=dict(lbfunc="my-func-dev")
)
# What should I pass to the handler variable so that LambdaRestApi triggers the lambda function specified by the stage variable "stageVariables.lbfunc"?
api = apigateway.LambdaRestApi(self, "my-api",
            rest_api_name="My Service",
            description="My Service API Gateway",
            handler=dev_lambda_function,    
            deploy_options=stage_options)
```

Comment: I had to change the permission LambdaIntegration generated automatically, ended up extending the class by myself - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59716246/9931092
I don't know if this is what you are looking for ( it's also in typescript) but this might be helpful. If you can add more information i would be happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this recently, I just record down how I solved it here *(before I forget)*

The idea here is, when your API method get hit, it will make a `POST` request your `lambda`. So you make a "URL" of your lambda, so your API method can hit that. *(Ok, I finally found it, you can read it here, for [item No.6 in this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html), look the URI there)*

1. Create a `Construct` called `ApiIntegration`:

   ```
   class ApiIntegration(core.Construct):

      @property
      def integration(self):
        return self._integration

       def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, function: _lambda,  ** kwargs):
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Here you construct a "URL" for your lambda
        api_uri = (
            f"arn:aws:apigateway:"
            f"{core.Aws.REGION}"
            f":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
            f"{function.function_arn}"
            f":"
            f"${{stageVariables.lambdaAlias}}" # this will appear in the picture u provide
            f"/invocations"
        )
        # Then here make a integration 
        self._integration = apigateway.Integration(
            type=apigateway.IntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
            integration_http_method="POST",
            uri=api_uri
        )
   ```
2. In your `MyStack(core.Stack)` class you can use it like this:

   ```
         # Here u define lambda, I not repeat again 
         my_lambda = ur lambda you define

         # define stage option 
         dev_stage_options = apigateway.StageOptions(
                               stage_name="dev",
                                   variables={
                                      "lambdaAlias": "dev" # define ur variable here
                               })
         # create an API, put in the stage options
         api = apigateway.LambdaRestApi(
                  self, "MyLittleNiceApi",
                  handler=my_lambda,
                  deploy_options=dev_stage_options
               )

         # Now use the ApiIntegration you create 
         my_integration = ApiIntegration(
             self, "MyApiIntegration", function=my_lambda)

        # make a method call haha
        my_haha_method = api.root.add_resource("haha")

        # put in the integration that define inside the Construct 
        my_haha_post_method = my_method.add_method('POST',
                              integration=my_integration.integration,
                              #...then whatever here)
   ```

By now you check your console, your method will have Lambda function with `stageVariable`.

Now you should create the `lambda alias`, the idea is like this:

- You have 1 lambda
- Make 2 alias for the lambda, `dev` and `prod`
- API stageVariable dev -> hit -> lambda `dev` alias
- API stageVariable prod -> hit -> lambda `prod` alias

Each lambda alias will hit different version of your lambda, for example:

- `dev` alias hit `$Latest`
- `prod` alias hit `version:12`

I have talk about this in [dev.to here](https://dev.to/upupkenchoong/comment/1b7f0)

Now you have `lambda:dev` and `lambda:prod` 2 alias.
In order to let your `method` to hit different alias `lambda:dev` and `lambda:prod`, you need `(The main idea)`:

> Lambda `dev/prod alias` give permission to `method` to hit on.

Create version, alias and permission stuff is whole different story, so didnt mention here.